# XML DATASET to be Validated

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

Hello all i have a scenario where i have

TWO XML FILES

one xml say "Books.xml" will create the schema for DATASET and i will use other XML file to load data into DATASET and all data in 2nd file will be inserted into DATASET

I have done these things but i m stuck at validating XML i want to validate 2nd xml file 
means data entered into dataset should be exactly valid according to DATASET schema which will be according to First XML

i have tried it using XSD but i am not sure if XSD will be able to validate TYPE of data say if i have to input number and i have a string in my xml ,it should throw an exception

i have my xml like this

```
<DATA>
  <HISTORY>
    <book1>SOmebook</book1>
  </HISTORY>
  <POETRY>
    <book2>Books</book2>
  </POETRY>
 </DATA>
```

and i am generating my XSD Using VisualStudio

to validate it im using a method something like this

```
XmlReaderSettings settings = //dont know exact settings
               string data = null;
               XmlReader Reader = XmlReader.Create(File.Open("C:\books.XML", FileMode.Open), settings, data);

            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            ds.ReadXml(Reader);
```

Comment: XML Schema **does** validate simple types, like `xs:string`, `xs:decimal`, `xs:integer`, `xs:boolean`, 'xs:date`, `xs:time`. If you use Linq2XML, the `Validate()` method lets you specify the schema. If the validation fails, you know that your XML is not valid. Custom object types are not that easy to validate. To me, creating a custom validator seems a bit to extreme.

Comment: oki thanks for your time andrei but can u show me how to use validate for linq2xml, as i am = null in xml things just started it

Comment: Have a look at this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387037.aspx). It shows a simple example for validating an XDocument against a Schema and also how to process errors. In this example the Schema is hardcoded but it's not difficult to load it from file. Have a look at the [XDocument class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx) for more info. There are tons of examples on how to use this class. Hope this helps.

Comment: Having another look at your XML, I must ask if the `<book1>` and `<book2>` tags are intensionally created different. Do you want to make an explicit distinction between the history books and poetry ones? If so, I would suggest more meaningful names (e.g. `<poetrybook>`). If not, you would probably want to use a "generic" `<book>`.

Comment: this is just a dummy xml original xml is far different from this and i have achieved what i was looking for by ur help and some changes in below code to fulfill my needs thnx very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a quick example on how you can use a schema to validate. I'm using the `shiporder` example from [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/schema_example.asp).

Schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

<xs:element name="shiporder">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="orderperson" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="shipto">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="address" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="city" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="country" type="xs:string"/>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="item" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="title" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="note" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xs:element name="quantity" type="xs:positiveInteger"/>
            <xs:element name="price" type="xs:decimal"/>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
   <xs:attribute name="orderid" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
 </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<shiporder orderid="889923">
  <orderperson>John Smith</orderperson>
    <shipto>
      <name>Ola Nordmann</name>
      <address>Langgt 23</address>
      <city>4000 Stavanger</city>
      <country>Norway</country>
   </shipto>
   <item>
     <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
     <note>Special Edition</note>
     <quantity>1</quantity>
     <price>10.90</price>
   </item>
   <item>
    <title>Hide your heart</title>
    <quantity>1</quantity> <!--Change to "one" to see validation error-->
    <price>9.90</price>
  </item>
</shiporder>
```

And here's the validation using Linq2XML:

```
XDocument document = XDocument.Load("shiporder.xml");
XmlSchemaSet schemas = new XmlSchemaSet();
schemas.Add("", XmlReader.Create("schema.xsd"));
bool errors = false;

document.Validate(schemas, (o, e) =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Validation error: {0}", e.Message);
        errors = true;
    });

    if (!errors)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("XML document successfully validated.");
    }
    else 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("XML document does not validate.");
    }
```

Change the value of of the `<quantity>` node as mentioned in the comment in order to see how the XML does not validate because of invalid type.